# does not want grouping symbol in google chart numbers

Tags: google-visualization

I am google chart to draw tables. I have a column of numbers but numbers are printed as "1,222,322" but i don't want grouping symbol(comma) between digits.
i tried

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ groupingSymbol: ' '});
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

seems to work fine here

make sure to format the column before drawing the chart

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['controls', 'table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['date', 'count'],
    [new Date('2016-09-29 06:47:47'), 1000001],
    [new Date('2016-09-29 14:48:42'), 1222322],
    [new Date('2016-10-29 06:47:47'), 3250805],
    [new Date('2016-11-29 06:48:42'), 1110588],
  ]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits: 0,
    groupingSymbol: ' '
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_div',
    dataTable: data
  });
  table.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: How can I make it to integer?

Comment: do you mean same as before, just without decimals? if so, add this to formatter --> `fractionDigits: 0` -- changed answer above...